# Can we use initWithNibName to reuse same .xib file with different views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nib, init

I have a UITableView which contains 8 items (static). Now when i click each of 8 cells then each cell contains 1 single control.

For example:

1. Click cell 1:   New view with UIPickerView.
2. Click cell 2:   Another view with UIDatePicker
3. Click cell 3:   One more view with UITextField.
   .
   ... so on.

Can I use **only one .xib** file which contains all the controls but when i click that cell only that control is visible and all other are hidden.

Also i want that those controls value should be return to detailText of Table Cell.

How can I reuse one .xib file??  can i invoke xib file with different nib names and check in initwithnibname method??

please can u give me good example for this....

Comment: you can have all controls in a single xib and show/hide based on cell selection.

Comment: But then how can i identify that which value is set in DetailView? Suppose click at cell 1 set the picker value in table. Click on cell 2, Date is set? and so on

Answer (score 0):

Basically the only way I find is to set conditional statements where in you show only some of the controls in a particular condition and hide the others and in other conditions similarly.

I think this is the only way you can show different controls based on cell selection in same XIB.

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

You can use a flag (declared in application delegate) and set the flag in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method based on the cell selected.

Now on the viewDidLoad of the PickerView, you can check the same flag which would let you know which cell was clicked.

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT-1**

You can just use the NSUserDefaults as shown..

For Cell-1

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Cell-1" forKey:@"CELLSELECTED"];
```

For Cell-2:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Cell-2" forKey:@"CELLSELECTED"];
```

For Cell-3:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"Cell-3" forKey:@"CELLSELECTED"];
```

and so on..

Hope this helps you now

Comment: but where should i write conditional statements in pickerView?? If in viewdidload i will write, then how can i get which table cell is clicked???

Comment: @DShah: Please check the **EDIT**  section of my answer.

Comment: yes this is one of the solution and obvious way... but then i have 10 rows and already there are so many variables so i was not opting this solution. If i am able to get setHidden Property working then it will make my code looks good.. :) and ofcourse i can relax of using 10 bool values...

Comment: @DShah: Ok you dont require 10 Boolean flags.. You just need one NSUserDerfaults value to make it work.. check my code above..

Comment: Finally the thing is same whether i use variables or user defaults. Its good that user default saves me from lots of variables. But my main question still remains as it is that WHY i cannot be able to get setHidden work, though i get setHidden as property in intellisense menu..???

Comment: @DShah:`"How can I reuse one .xib file?? can i invoke xib file with different nib names and check in initwithnibname method??"` This is what your question asks so I am replying as per that...got it..!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this brilliant idea of using generic nib files on a Prefs screen, so I had a "switch nib", a "text field nib", and a "text nib".  I assigned the controls to view controller properties programmatically in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  However, this ended up not functioning for some mysterious reason.

I ended up designing a custom nib for each cell.  It works.  Then, in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have to determine which cell was loaded, to initialize the control to the proper value.

Comment: so you mean that i should create controls on didSelect or cellForRowAtIndexPath methods?? Or you want me to create different nibs for all cells???